# How to get wp types taxonomy using post id?

Tags: wordpress

I have created custom taxonomy using wordpress wp types plugin. How i can get wp types taxonomy using post id.I need to get taxonomy using particular post id.Please  help.

Answer (score 1):

As in the [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms):

```
<?php $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy, $args ); ?>
```

Replace `$taxonomy` and ommit `$args`:

```
<?php $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'taxonomy_name_here' ); ?>
```

and that should do it.